# Mocking in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, easymock

I'm attempting to test the `isKeyguardSecure()` method of the [KeyguardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isDeviceSecure()) class in an Android application.

I've tried and failed using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org), [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), and [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to create a mock `KeyguardManager` object.  Below are my attempts and the error messages received.

---

**EasyMock**

`KeyguardManager keyguardManagerMock = EasyMock.createMock(KeyguardManager.class);`

Error message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.app.KeyguardManager is not an interface`

---

**Mockito and PowerMock**

`KeyguardManager mockedKeyguardManager = Mockito.mock(KeyguardManager.class);`
`KeyguardManager mockedKeyguardManager = PowerMockito.mock(KeyguardManager.class);`

Error messages: `java.lang.VerifyError: mockit/internal/startup/Startup`
`java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils`

---

[One explanation for this](http://www.developerblogger.com/21_23512996/) states that the root problem is with the Dalvik virtual machine that Android devices run.  Can anyone verify this?  Is it possible to mock the `KeyguardManager` class using any available mocking library that will work in testing an Android app?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to test the functionality of a built-in method?

Answer (score 1):

Your EasyMock version is too old. PowerMock isn't required for that. Using EasyMock 3.4, I did the following and it worked perfectly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyguardManager manager = createMock(KeyguardManager.class);
    expect(manager.isKeyguardSecure()).andReturn(true);
    replay(manager);
    assertTrue(manager.isKeyguardSecure());
    verify(manager);
}
```

Comment: Did you try this in an Android project?  When I attempt to run your code in an Android project, I receive the error: `java.lang.VerifyError: org/easymock/cglib/core/ReflectUtils`

Comment: Interesting. I'm running it from the EasyMock Android test project. Cglib should not be used for Android. You can debug in `org.easymock.internal.AndroidSupport` to see if it behaves correctly. Can you please create a demo project showing the error? It might be a bug in EasyMock.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerMock with EasyMock.

Dependencies:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.3.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:1.6.2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
```

Sample code:

```
package com.example.user.exampleapp;

import android.app.KeyguardManager;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(KeyguardManager.class)
public class KeyguardTest {

    @Test
    public void testKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager keyguardMock = PowerMock.createMock(KeyguardManager.class);
        EasyMock.expect(keyguardMock.isKeyguardSecure()).andReturn(false);
        PowerMock.replayAll();
        System.out.println("is locked " + keyguardMock.isKeyguardSecure());
        PowerMock.verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
is locked false
```

Comment: Did you try this in an Android project?  When I attempt to run your code in an Android project, I receive the error: `java.lang.VerifyError: org/easymock/cglib/core/ReflectUtils`

Comment: @spookymodem yes I compiled it and run in Android Studio, the output is real from console.